# Определенный шрифт при создании картинки

Tags: php, изображения

Всм првт гспд!

```
// Создание изображения
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Создание цветов
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// Текст надписи
$text = 'Тест...';
// Замена пути к шрифту на пользовательский
$font = 'tahoma.ttf';

// Текст
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

imagepng($im,'image_name.png');
```

Собственно создание изображения с надписью.. все вроде хорошо. А можно как то сделать, что бы скрипт не использовал файл tahoma.ttf ? Ну можно просто не указывать шрифт, но тогда он будет не Tahoma, а какой то стандартный-моношрифт.. Вот охота указать название шрифта, и что бы этот шрифт использовался (как по аналогии с css)

Если есть эксперты по этому вопросу - отзовитесь!

Comment: Загружаете в какую-нибудь папку проекта (например, 'fonts') нужный вам шрифт (например, 'lobster.ttf').  
Указываете путь к этому шрифту, опуская первый слэш:  

    $font = 'fonts/lobster.ttf';
    imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

Все. В чем сложность?

Comment: А можно ли лишь указать тип шрифта, чтоб он его как в css нашел? (допустим в css если указать Tahoma - css сам его найдет - т.к. он стандартный)

Comment: Нет, семейство шрифтов указывать нельзя, поскольку обрабатывается 1 конкретный файл. Вам придется написать собственный класс для реализации такой логики, но при этом учтите, что все файлы шрифтов используемые в проекте должны быть в одной с ним папке.

Comment: ок. Теперь хоть понял, что такое нельзя (по крайней мере пока)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ні, доведеться качати шрифт і юзати. Сам цього не люблю. Хотілось, би, як в css і правда.